# Sorted insertion into small (255 element) list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for a suitable algorithm to build a relatively small (up to 255 elements) sorted array of integers. The target platform is a STM32 based embedded system. Since memory is limited, an in-place method is preferred.

I am aware that the obvious way is implement and profile the usual suspects (quick sort, insert sert, shell sort), but would like to ask for your experiences nevertheless. More specifically I have found very little information on the performance when *building* the array - that is, how well different algorithms may use the fact that all existing elements are already ordered.

**Edit 1:** 
Although the question is tagged C++ the STL is not available. Furthermore, the sorting does indeed occur inside a inner loop. To further clarify, I am looking for an algorithm that is especially suited to *build* a sorted list in an efficient manner. I assume (maybe wrongly) there must be algorithms specially suited for this task. That's the question.

**Edit 2:**
When saying *building* a sorted list I mean that the list starts empty and is filled by by a bounded number (max 255) of 16-bit integers which are in no particular order. The list must be processed after all elements have been stored. For processing the list must be sorted, preferably in descending order.

Thanks in advance,
Arne

Comment: Do you have a question?  Or are you simply asking us to "send teh codez"?

Comment: @abelenky NO, I do not ask anyone to "send teh codez"! Instead I wonder, which part of the above text left this impression, leading to your down-vote. I would like to direct your attention to the second paragraph "[...] would like to ask [...]".

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`?  Answers differ.  I assume C++, so just use `std::sort`.  It's fast enough 99.9% of the time, and in place.

Comment: Only 255 elements? unless this sorting occures very often, you are not expected to see any performance change between different sorts. just use simple max-sort or bubble sort - or the **one you find easiest to implement**.

Comment: @MooingDuck Although we use a subset of C++ for this project the STL is not available.

Comment: For 255 elements, you won't see any big difference whatever method you choose (for the user, 4 microseconds is exactly the same as 4 milliseconds). So go with the one you understand best.

Comment: What is the *range* of the integers being stored.

Comment: @Arne: You say several times "building a sorted list" and I feel like that is significant, but I don't understand how.  Are you sorting random data or do you have mostly sorted data that you want to keep sorting?

Comment: Is there a requirement that the list has to exist sorted at all times in memory, or does it just have to be sorted after inserting all the elements?  If the latter, and you know the maximum number of inserts is 255, why not insert them in the order found, then sort it when insertion completes?  `O(n + n log n)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your problem demands that:

- you store your elements fully sorted in an actual C/C++ array, and
- you maintain your items in sorted order at all times,

then you've painted yourself into a corner:  your requirements spell "insertion sort".

No matter what algorithm or auxiliary datastructure you choose, inserting a new element in the middle will require you to move the larger elements up by an index, and deleting any element (except the largest) will require you to move the larger elements down by an index.  Since an insertion sort does exactly that, without any additional logic or datastructure, you might as well use it.

The only exception is if your comparison is particularly expensive.  If that is the case, then you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find your insertion point (instead of comparing your new element against each old element as you move it).  However, you will still need to move all elements larger than the mutation point, so you will never be able to improve your performance past O(N) (although a bulk data move should be pretty fast...).

Also, you should evaluate your requirements:  if you know that `N < 256`, and the worst case of inserting an object in position `0` is fast enough for your application, you should stop there.  There's no point in making things more complicated than necessary, to save time you don't need.

---

On the other hand, if:

- you don't actually need to keep all elements fully sorted at all times, and
- what you *do* actually need is to repeatedly find and remove the largest/smallest element in the array

then what you need is called a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), and you can implement it (in memory-efficient, in-place fashion) by using an [implicit heap](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node5.html).  Implicit heap operations are O(log N), and typically have a good performance factor; even for `N = 255`, this can make a big difference in worst-case performance.

Comment: @commingstorm: I highly appreciate your mentioning of an implicit heap. That is exactly the *kind* of suggestions I was looking for - even though evaluation of the hint may or may not be the final solution.

Comment: Investigating the implicit heap, I bet it has been mentioned before but without the explicit naming. Kudos to who-ever it was!

Answer (score 3):

I often use this algo in microcontroller environment, it keeps the table always sorted. It doesn't use binary lookup, but the loop that searches a greater element will run faster then binary algorithm if you only going to use it for a small number of elements. For larger arrays, you may want to do a binary lookup.

This algorithm is also very easy to implement in assembler and only uses 2 additional int's on stack.

```
#define TABLE_SIZE 255
int table[TABLE_SIZE];
int tableUsed = 0;

bool AddToTable(int value)
{
    int i;

    if (tableUsed >= TABLE_SIZE)
        return false;

    // Find location to insert value
    for (i = 0; i < tableUsed; i++)
        if (table[i] > value)
            break;
    // Insert value
    do
    {
        table[i] ^= value;
        value ^= table[i];
        table[i] ^= value;
    } while (i++ < tableUsed);

    tableUsed++;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: does that xor trick actually run faster than a simple element shift in the array? sounds very counterintuitive.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: The `xor` thing is an in-place-swap, which is probably slower than `std::swap` on modern processors.

Comment: a swap instruction is indeed preferred over this xor trick if the controller supports it

Answer (score 1):

Honestly for something like this, I'd just do a shell sort and call it good.  You can hard code the skip elements into a register/asm friendly format to prevent that from leaking onto the stack.  Plus, the performance will be very close to `O(log(n))`.  That and you can code it or copy it from elsewhere almost instantly.  Very small code/mem footprint as well.  This was my sort of choice on a very, very similar situation on a GBA game sorting actor by (int) Y depths.

Comment: I will give Shell sort a try as it seems reasonably easy to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to frequently be sorting an array of integers that is already sorted, or partially sorted, then [smooth sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort) might be a good choice.  It requires O(1) auxiliary storage, runs in O(n log n) in the worst case, and as the input array becomes more sorted the runtime approaches O(n).

I've only ever really compared smooth sort with quick sort.  I'll post some of the numbers here, but more numbers and a Go implementation of smooth sort are available [here](https://github.com/runningwild/sorts).

Number of swaps and comparisons on 1k elements:

```
                        swaps comparisons
Quicksort on sorted:      682       15896
Smoothsort on sorted:       0        2481
Quicksort on reversed:   1122       15587
Smoothsort on reversed: 10708       26436
```

Smoothsort on 1k elements:

```
Sorted        101431 ns/op
MostlySorted  550455 ns/op
Shuffled       95635 ns/op
Reversed      730083 ns/op
```

Quicksort on 1k elements:

```
Sorted        243270 ns/op
MostlySorted  299113 ns/op
Shuffled       39798 ns/op
Reversed      245046 ns/op
```

Comment: you have `ns/op`, but not the total times?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do an [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), unless you know the distribution of the data.  That's a [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with maximum depth of log(n), then it switches to either [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) depending on the size left. (In your case, that will *always* be insertion sort.

If you know the distribution of the data, you might try a [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).  For instance, if they're evenly distributed, between 0 and 2147483648, count how many are in each "range" of 46341ish values, and then rearrange them into the correct "range".  Then sort each "range".  I explained that terribly so heres an example (with values 0-15, ranges of 4 values)

```
start: 5, 11, 14, 2, 6, 9, 7, 12, 12, 7, 10, 12, 0, 10, 12, 3, 13, 10
count: There are 3 in the range of 0-3
       There are 4 in the range of 4-7
       There are 5 in the range of 8-11
       There are 6 in the range of 12-15
bucket:[0-3]      [4-7]         [8-11]               [12-15]
       [?, ?, ?], [?, ?, ?, ?], [?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?],  [?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?]
       [2, 0, 3], [5, 6, 7, 7], [11, 9,  10, 10, 10], [14, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13]
sort:  [0, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 7], [9,  10, 10, 10, 11], [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 14]
```

For that last step, you simply do any fast sort on each of the small "buckets".  It's hard to do in-place though.  (I've done it, but it's hard)  Quicksort is much easier to program.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented [comb sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort) for relatively small lists (<1000) on SPEs (not quite embedded processors, but they have serious limitations) with good results -- small memory footprint, in-place sort, `n log n` average complexity with `n` best case, not prone to quicksort's poor median choice problems, easy to understand, and simple to implement.

The only real annoyance I might see is most implementation's tendency to use floating point ops to calculate the gap size -- but you can usually skirt that if you're careful.

Answer (score 0):

If your list were larger, timsort would be excellent - it's Supernaturally Fast (tm), and does very well with already sorted, or mostly sorted, arrays.  Both Python and Java use timsort now in their standard libraries.

Since you have a small array, I'd probably do an insertion sort or bubble sort (!).  The variant of a bubble sort that keeps going until no adjacent values are exchanged would likely be pretty nice here.

Don't let people tell you all sorts are the same for this - the sorts that are good for huge arrays tend to have higher constants than the sorts that are good at small arrays, and the constants can be a big deal at low values of n.  That's why a great sorting algorithm will generally use an nlogn sort in the large, but switch to a low constant, O(n^2) algorithm for small sublists.

But is an array really the best choice?  If you're messing with this datastructure a lot, you might be better served by a treap or red-black tree.  Both of these datastructures are always sorted, and can do almost any operation in O(logn) time (except getting a sorted list, which is O(n)).  Treaps give better average operation time than red-black trees, but red-black tree operation durations have a lower variance.  This is because treaps are almost always faster than red-black trees, but treaps will infrequently do a big, internal reorganization that could try an enduser's patience for large n.

As another poster mentioned, you might consider a heap as well, but you're saying you need things always sorted, so probably an array, treap or red-black tree is what you need.